# Can't update Azure Storage Blob metadata while setting metadata

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have Azure Function which resizes image.

```
[FunctionName(nameof(ResizeBlob))]
public static async Task ResizeBlob(
   [BlobTrigger("originals/{name}")] CloudBlockBlob inputBlob,
   [Blob("resized/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream outputBlob,
   ILogger log)
{
    await inputBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();

    if (!inputBlob.Metadata.ContainsKey("Resized") || inputBlob.Metadata["Resized"] == bool.FalseString)
    {
        var inputBlobStream = await inputBlob.OpenReadAsync();

        using (var image = Image.Load(inputBlobStream))
        {
            image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(1920, 1080));
            image.Save(outputBlob, new JpegEncoder());

            // If comment next statements, everything is ok, otherwise - it's not saving correctly
            inputBlob.Metadata["ResizedFHD"] = bool.TrueString;
            await inputBlob.SetMetadataAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Because I can't stop triggering [BlobTrigger] on metadata update, I need to solve the problem of multiple file resizing by adding special metadata. However, after resizing, I can't set this metadata - it cause 0-length object.

[image]

But if I comment the lines with metadata update, everything is work fine and blob is created ok.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I test your code, it could work for me even deploy it to azure. So then I change `outputBlob` binding to `CloudBlockBlob` and use `UploadFromStreamAsync` to upload the blob then I got the same problem. After researching I suppose it's caused by `image.Save()` method, with JpegEncoder the stream should set the right position.

The below code is my `CloudBlockBlob` type code, you could have a try.

```
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([BlobTrigger("image/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]CloudBlockBlob inputBlob,
            [Blob("resized/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] CloudBlockBlob outputBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {

            if (!inputBlob.Metadata.ContainsKey("Resized") || inputBlob.Metadata["Resized"] == bool.FalseString)
            {
                var inputBlobStream = await inputBlob.OpenReadAsync();
                System.IO.MemoryStream blobstream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

                using (var image = Image.Load(inputBlobStream))
                {

                    image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(1920, 1080));
                    image.Save(blobstream , new JpegEncoder());

                    blobstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    await outputBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(blobstream);

                    // If comment next statements, everything is ok, otherwise - it's not saving correctly
                    inputBlob.Metadata["ResizedFHD"] = bool.TrueString;
                    await inputBlob.SetMetadataAsync();
                }

            }
```

And if you still want to use `Stream outputBlob` binding maybe you could use the same way, just change a few lines of code.

```
image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(1920, 1080));
//image.Save(outputBlob, new JpegEncoder());

image.Save(blobstream, new JpegEncoder());
blobstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
blobstream.CopyTo(outputBlob, 1024);
```

Suppose these two ways could work, if you still have confusions about your function, please provide more information or your environments so I will have a more detailed test.